# TotalPrice (rollup summary field) on quote shows wrong values

Tags: quote, quotelineitem

I have a **quote** with quotelineitems (worth 1000). The totalprice displayed on quote details page shows **`$1000`** 
, the right value, but when i query the total price i see **9,99.99999** 
And we have quiet few quotes with discrepancy in total price. any ideas ?

Comment: In the rollup summary field, what is the precision set?

Comment: that is a standard field. We dont have that option.

Comment: 9,999.99999 can be shown as $10,000 and not $1,000

Comment: what do you see if you query the quotelineitems? There might be a lineitem with that .99999 precision. On the detail page indeed it will round towards less decimals.

Comment: @o-lexi updated the question, thanks

Comment: none of the lines have decimal values.

Comment: You can set values by Apex code or API calls with the number of decimals other than what is set in the field properties. Salesforce doesn't do validations on this. But it will display number of decimals you've defined in the field properties. For Roll-Up formulas this might be taken from the setting of the field on detail object

Comment: @o-lexi we are not setting decimal values from APEX or API calls, just double checked it.  " For Roll-Up formulas this might be taken from the setting of the field on detail object  " Detail object specifies for 2 decimals. So i guess that is not doing that too :(

Comment: @o-lexi can you post this as answer? One of the line item did come through an api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying discounts, unusual pricing, etc, can cause this to happen. The currency fields only show up to two decimal places, but the internal capacity of number fields are much greater. You should avoid applying odd discounts that create odd unit prices. Discounting 10% off of 1000 is just fine, but discounting 7% from 987.65 results in an internal value of 918.5145 (which would appear as 918.51). The total fields on both Opportunity and Quote behave this way, so you should make sure that the values line up correctly. You'll need to query the individual line items to figure out the source of the rounding.